# Terraform module as "custom function"

Tags: module, terraform, output

It is possible to use some i.e. local module to return let' say same calculated output. But how can you pass some parameters? So each time you will ask for the output value you will get different value according to the parameter(ie different prefix)

Is it possible to pass resource to module and enhance it with tags?

I can imagine that both cases are more likely to be case for providers, but for some simple case it should work maybe. The best would be if they implemented some custom function that you will be able to call at will.

Comment: It depends on the resource. And you can do anything what you want with local-exec anyway and custom data sources, so everything is possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to generate some module output string based on parameters which differ every time? Let's say params are some prefix and integer which needs to be joined in module.

Comment: Sadly you haven't provided any example, so its difficult to speculate what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to name let's say Azure resource group. So I like to somehow create module, which output will be used as the name of created resource. This is probably simple, but the name needs to contain some changing parametr aka sequence. So I would like to call something like `module.output.name(sequence number) `and it will output the name  containing the sequence. Only way how can I imagine it to work is to create module per  sequence and gets its output, but is quite verbose.

Comment: `module.output.name(sequence number)` you can't do that.

Comment: yes I know, this is what the question is about. How to simulate this? [Here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aztfmod/azurecaf/latest/docs/resources/azurecaf_name) they use provider and "naming resource", but for sequence number to work you still need to create resource per seq. number. Using just module and concatenate the values will be easier. But seams unfeasible.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible in principle to write a Terraform module that only contains "named values", which is the broad term for the three module features [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html) (analogous to function arguments), [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html) (analogous to local declarations inside your function), and [Output Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html) (analogous to return values).

Such a module would not contain any `resource` or `data` blocks at all and would therefore be a "computation-only" module, which therefore has all of the same capabilities as a function in a functional programming language.

```
variable "a" {
  type = number
}

variable "b" {
  type = number
}

locals {
  sum = var.a + var.b
}

output "sum" {
  value = local.sum
}
```

The above example is contrived just to show the principle. A "function" this simple doesn't really need the local value `local.sum`, because its expression could just be written inline in the value of `output "sum"`, but I wanted to show examples of all three of the relevant constructs here.

You would "call the function" by declaring a module call referring to the directory containing the file with the above source code in it:

```
module "example" {
  source = "./modules/sum"

  a = 1
  b = 2
}

output "result" {
  value = module.example.sum
}
```

I included the `output "result"` block here to show how you can refer to the result of the "function" elsewhere in your module, as `module.example.sum`.

Of course, this syntax is much more "chunky" than a typical function call, so in practice Terraform module authors will use this approach only when the factored out logic is significant enough to justify it. Verbosity aside though, you can include as many `module` blocks referring to that same module as you like if you need to call the "function" with different sets of arguments. Each call to the module can take a different set of input variable values and therefore produce a different result.

Comment: The problem is I'd like to get different values without the need to create new and new module definition. But seams like this is how it works in TF and there is no other way. Imagine I'd like to name 20 resource groups and without the possibility to change the inputs I need to create 20 module definitions.

Comment: Yes, each `module` block represents a single call to the "function". However, if you can express all of the calls you need systematically then you could potentially write a single `module` block using [the `for_each` argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html), which will effectively give you a map value containing various different results of calling your "function".

Comment: can you please elaborate on the for_each, so far I have one output with map and getting per typ naming like this 'module.output.names["type"]'. I will investigate the for_each.